# Using maven cxf plugin cxf-codegen-plugin java artifacts from WSDL

Tags: maven, cxf, cxf-codegen-plugin

Using maven cxf plugin cxf-codegen-plugin java artifacts from WSDL. But the javacodes are not populating in the eclipse IDE.

Do I need to specify the any other tags to get the java source code in the eclipse project.

Below is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SampleMavenPluginStubCreation</groupId>
  <artifactId>SampleMavenPluginStubCreation</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
   <build>
        <finalName>SampleMavenPluginStubCreation</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Generate Java classes from WSDL during build -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/wsdl/workorder.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.apache.cxf
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            cxf-codegen-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [2.1.2,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                 <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

       <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/java/</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
 </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
   </build>
</project>
```

This is my folder structure.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate the sources and *then* get Eclipse to know where they came from.

1. The first step is done by right-clicking on the top-level project and choosing “Run As” → “Maven generate-sources”. This should build them below the project's `target/generated-sources` directory.
2. The second step is done by right-clicking on the top-level project and choosing “Maven” → “Update Project…”. You'll then need to make sure that the project is selected in the dialog; that might be trivial (I have rather a lot of projects open in my Eclipse, but yours may be simpler). The option that you *need* to have switched on in the dialog is “Update project configuration from pom.xml” though a general update of everything else shouldn't be harmful.

You may need to redo this every time you update the source WSDL. In practice, it only takes a few seconds, so it's not very onerous.

Answer (score 1):

The recent versions (as in all releases in the last couple years) of the CXF plugins have the M2E lifecycle stuff built in.  Upgrade to 2.7.14 or 3.0.3 and a lot of your issues would be fixed.  (along with a TON of other bugs and security issues)